# Excel formula for first day of the week without holidays

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Want to know the excel formula for the first business day of the week without holidays. So far I have

=D2-WEEKDAY(D2,2)+1

where D2 is today's date. This formula is giving me the first day of the week but I also want it to skip holidays.

Comment: You may want to look into [`NETWORKDAYS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48E717BF-A7A3-495F-969E-5005E3EB18E7) and/or [`NETWORKDAYS.INTL`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/networkdays-intl-function-a9b26239-4f20-46a1-9ab8-4e925bfd5e28)

Answer (score 0):

You want to wrap the return date in WORKDAY and locate a list of holidays(I put mine in column F)

```
=WORKDAY(D2-WEEKDAY(D2,2),1,F1:F8)
```

[image]